# How do you put a ViewBag item into a Text Box?

Tags: c#

I have the following code and I get an error saying:

```
 has no applicable method named 'TextBoxFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
```

My Code:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(ViewBag.taglist)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use strongly typed model in your view instead of `ViewBag`. This will make your life easier.

In fact, you must use a model to with `TextBoxFor`, otherwise it just won't work. See the definition of [TextBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) - as a second parameter it takes a lambda expression that takes a property form a model.

If you want just a text box, two options:

```
@Html.TextBox("NameOfTheTextbox", (String)ViewBag.SomeValue)
```

or just go

```
<input type="text" value="@ViewBag.SomeValue" />
```

No complex solutions required.

Comment: Well how would  I display the viewbag item within a text box without needing to reference the model.

Comment: use `Html.TextBox` for that.

Comment: You could write your own html.  Or you could write your own html helper.  The *For methods are for binding form fields and model elements.

Comment: I find it weird there isn't just a simple solution to this problem. Why did Microsoft not think of implementing something for this problem without needing a workaround.

Comment: use it like this: `@Html.TextBox("NameOfTheTextbox", (String)ViewBag.SomeValue)`

Comment: This throws an exception see my other comment.

Comment: sure, because you are trying to cast a db-query to a string. Put a string into a view bag, then output it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with other suggestions of using a strongly-typed model, because the compile-time error support is so much better than debugging exceptions.  Having said that, in order to do what you want, you can use this:

```
@Html.TextBox("NameOfTextBox", (string)ViewBag.taglist)
```

#### Update: A Simple Example

Now that you've provided some details in your comments, I've taken a guess at what you might be doing, in order to provide a simple example.

I'm assuming you have a list of tags (like SO has per question) that you'd like to display neatly in a textbox, with each tag separated by a space.  I'm going to assume your `Tag` domain model looks something like this:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now, your view will need a list of the tags but will likely need some other information to be displayed as well.  However, let's just focus on the tags. Below is a view model to represent all the tags, taking into account that you want to display them as a string inside a textbox:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

In order to get the data you want you could grab all of the tags like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (YourContext db = new YourContext())
    {
        var model = new SomeViewModel();
        model.Tags = string.Join(" ", db.Tags.Select(t => t.Description).ToList());

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Notice how I'm directly passing `model` to the view.

The view is now very simple:

```
@model SomeViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tags)
```

The `model` directive is what signifies that a view is strongly-typed.  That means this view will expect to receive an instance of `SomeViewModel`.  As you can see from my action code above, we will be providing this view the type that it wants.  This now allows us to make use of the strongly-typed `HtmlHelper` (i.e. `Html.XxxFor`) methods.

In this particular case, I've used `Html.EditorFor`, as it will choose an appropriate input element to render the data with. (In this case, because `Description` is a `string`, it will render a textbox.)

Comment: Just kidding. It threw an error at runtime  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<GamingQuest.Models.Tag>' to 'string'

Comment: so you tried to cast a DbQuery class to a string? no wonder it did not work. Everyone here presumed you put a string into ViewBag.taglist

Comment: @NoahR This also goes back to why you should be using actual view models.  Knowing how to design and handle data is very important.  Slapping everything through `ViewBag` isn't a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, whoops, didn't realize it.

Comment: @NoahR I've added an example, which will hopefully make things a bit clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Html.TextBoxFor` without explicitly setting a type for your model within the view. If you don't specify a type it defaults to `dynamic`. If you want to do model binding then you must use an explicit type rather than a dynamic type like `ViewBag`.  To use `Html.TextBoxFor` you must define a model type that defines the property that you wish to bind. Otherwise you have to use `Html.TextBox` and set the value manually from `ViewBag`.  As others have said, you will make your life much easier if you use a statically typed model and take advantage of the inbuilt MVC model binding.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a lambda expression to select the property, plus you will have to cast the ViewBag member to the correct type.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => (string)ViewBag.taglist)
```

Comment: I still get an error saying "A expression tree may not contain a dynamic expression."

Comment: You get that expression, because you can't use ViewBag like that

Comment: down-voting because this is won't compile -(

Comment: You could cast it before using it in the expression.

Comment: no, no casting will help you here. Html.TextBoxFor must use a model, because it looks up model's metadata

Comment: Oops, hadn't even registered that we were using the "For" specific helper. The Html.TextBox() helper should be the one for use in this case. I was, however, correct that the type needed to be cast from dynamic before being used with the mvc helpers.